# Nytimes-style popup when the user makes a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you select text in an article on nytimes.com this little ? pops up at the end your selection:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/1316/827200941520pm.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/1316/827200941520pm.png)

What's the best way to implement something like this on my site? Are there any pre-rolled libraries for doing this?

Comment: I would just like to say I HATE this feature. I highlight text while I read and this bugs me each and every time. Fortunately it's not nearly as intrusive as it used to be. It used to pop up a dictionary window automatically, covering all the surrounding text.

Comment: I agree 100% this feature on the nytimes sucks. However, I'm going to use it for an entirely different purpose -- there's a part of my site that requires users to annotate text, and I'm planning to use this method to show the "create annotation" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NYT code is here

http://graphics8.nytimes.com/js/common/screen/altClickToSearch.js

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd have to do something like this.

```
$('div.selectableText').mouseUp(function(e){
        if (window.getSelection()){
            var xCoord = e.pageX;
            var yCoord = e.pageY;

            //Use the coordinates (or maybe offset) 
              to position your little modal popup
        }

)};
```

Comment: note: in IE you need to use `document.selection.createRange().text`